# webots - Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: unsatisfiedlinkerror, webots

I want to write Java-controllers for a webots Simulation. But whenever I try to build the Controller I get the error:

```
"Native code library failed to load. 
See the chapter on Dynamic Linking Problems in the SWIG Java documentation for help. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Webots\lib\JavaController.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" .
```

webots requires a 32-bit jdk, which I have installed. I also tried to change the java-command in the preferences from javaw.exe to java -d32. It didn´t help. I also generated the code with Intellij, where I changed the SDK-option to the 32 bit version. I also developed the controller in the editor of webots and built it there. Nothing run. Does anyone knows this problem and has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the error message you get, that Webots still launches the 64 bit version of the java virtual machine. I would recommend to uninstall this 64 bit version of Java to be sure that Webots is using the 32 bit version.

By the way, it seems you are not using the latest version of Webots which is now 64-bit only. So, another option for you would be to upgrade to Webots 8.3.1 (or newer) and use the 64 bit Java virtual machine.

Comment: You're right, I am not using the latest version of webots, because our professor provided us this version (I need it for studying). I don't want to delete java 64 bit virtual machine, I use it in other projects. Now I have installed the latest webots version and it runs. Unfortunately it is only a 30 days test version.